# Change the default color of a sidebar template

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I want to change the color of the text of the sidebar template that I get from the internet. But it's not changing even I'm in the right class. Any help please.

Here is the image.

[image: Sidebar Image]

I want to make the text for the "Superadmins" and "Admin Logs" colored white. But when I change it, it looks like kind of gray? How can I make it look white?

Here's the html code for sidebar.

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
     <ul id="sidebarnav" class="p-t-30">
      <li class="sidebar-item"> <a class="sidebar-link waves-effect waves-dark sidebar-link" href="index.php" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-home"></i><span class="hide-menu">Home</span></a></li>
      <li class="sidebar-item"> <a class="sidebar-link waves-effect waves-dark sidebar-link" href="superadmin.php" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i><span class="hide-menu"> Superadmins</span></a></li>
      <li class="sidebar-item"> <a class="sidebar-link waves-effect waves-dark sidebar-link" href="logs.php" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="hide-menu"> Admin Logs</span></a></li>
                      
     </ul>
     </li>
     
     </ul>
   </nav>
```

Here is the css code.

```
.sidebar-nav ul {
    color: #fff;
}
.sidebar-nav li .hide-menu {
    color: #fff;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .sidebar-link {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 14px 15px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .sidebar-link i {
    font-style: normal;
    width: 35px;
    line-height: 25px;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .sidebar-link.active,
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .sidebar-link:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
/* sidebar-hover */
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item.selected > .sidebar-link { 
    background: #27a9e3;
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .first-level {
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .first-level .sidebar-item.active .sidebar-link {
    opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .first-level .sidebar-item .sidebar-link {
    padding: 10px 15px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .first-level .sidebar-item .sidebar-link i {
    font-size: 14px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .nav-small-cap {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 14px 15px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.3;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.sidebar-nav ul .nav-small-cap i {
    line-height: 30px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
.sidebar-nav > #sidebarnav > .sidebar-item > .sidebar-link:hover {
}
.sidebar-nav ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.sidebar-nav ul li {
    color: #fff;
    list-style: none;
}
.collapse.in {
    display: block;
}
.sidebar-nav .has-arrow {
    position: relative;
}
.sidebar-nav .has-arrow:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    width: 7px;
    height: 7px;
    border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #fff;
    margin-left: 10px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg) translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(135deg) translate(0, -50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg) translate(0, -50%);
    transform: rotate(135deg) translate(0, -50%);
    -webkit-transform-origin: top;
    -ms-transform-origin: top;
    -o-transform-origin: top;
    transform-origin: top;
    top: 26px;
    right: 15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.sidebar-nav .has-arrow[aria-expanded="true"]:after,
.sidebar-nav li.active > .has-arrow:after,
.sidebar-nav li > .has-arrow.active:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(0, -50%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(0, -50%);
    -o-transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(0, -50%);
    transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(0, -50%);
}
```

Here is the image when I change the color of the hover.

[image: Hover]

Here is the code for the hover.

```
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item.selected > .sidebar-link { 
    background: #fff;
    color:#4e73df;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of opacity:

```css
/*...*/
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .sidebar-link {
    /*...*/
    opacity: 0.6;
}
/*...*/
```

You have to set it to 1 and play with text color's alpha component instead if you need. Pay attention, that there are several places, where opacity is used.

Comment: Last question, how can I make look the hover color to be the same as the sidebar color?

Comment: I think you should work with selectors which include `:hover` pseudoclass. Just add there `color:#4e73df` or another color of your choice.

Comment: Hello it does not work? here is the code: .sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item.selected > .sidebar-link { 
    background: #27a9e3;
    color:#4e73df;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1;
}

Comment: As I said, you have to edit this rules:
`
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .sidebar-link.active,
.sidebar-nav ul .sidebar-item .sidebar-link:hover {
    color:#4e73df;
    opacity: 1;
}
.sidebar-nav > #sidebarnav > .sidebar-item > .sidebar-link:hover {
    color:#4e73df;
}
`
they contain `:hover`

Comment: Already done it. I mean I want to make the active hover like in the home to be it's color is the same as the sidebar, I don't want to make it look white, and make the hover color white.

Comment: I edited the question. Please take a look

Comment: I hope, this will help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bklz3lGTFi8

Comment: I tried it but it's the same as the picture I uploaded.